# Nginx - Setting cache-control headers for dynamic content

Tags: nginx, wordpress

We are trying to implement cache-control headers for dynamic files, specifically WordPress.

For example, a sitemap generated by a plugin domain.com/sitemap_index.xml

The sitemap_index.xml doesn't actually exist, its dynamically controlled by WordPress and more specifically a plugin.  We are trying to ensure its not being cached by setting cache-control headers example:

```
   location ~* \.(xml)$ {
   add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
```

While the location block does work, if you were to remove the try_files then the page throws a 404 since WP is not handling the request, but the Cache-Control header does NOT get set.

If you create the file to test then the cache-control header does get set.

Is it just impossible to set the headers on dynamic content and needs to be done via PHP/the application itself?

Thank you for any and all feedback.

Comment: You can certainly make it work, but setting appropriate caching directives is something the application _should_ already be doing.

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't use `add_header` when returning a 404 response, if you don't specify `always` in the `add_header` directive.

From nginx's documentation page on [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) (*emphasis mine*):

> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals   **200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0)**. Parameter value can contain variables.

and

> If the **`always`** parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field **will be added regardless of the response code**.

Try to change your configuration to something like this:

```
location ~* \.(xml)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0" always;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work `add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0" always;` the cache-control header is still not set, and the XML doesn't throw a 404 while it doesn't physically exist PHP does generate the page or is it a 404 in nginx eyes since PHP is further down the chain?

Comment: I missed that dynamic XML generation -- there's no `Cache-Control` header in your `sitemap.xml` response because it's not processed by `location ~* \.xml$` block, but rather it's processed by your PHP block. Please edit your question to add more info about your PHP block, or better, post the result of `nginx -T` there.